# find substring between "a" and "(" + 2 unknown characters +")"

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have some strings which are built this way:

```
string = "blabla y the_blabla_I_want (two_digits_number) blabla"
```

I would like to get the_blabla_I_want. 
I know the `re.search` can help but my problem is about how to represent `(two_digits_number)`.

Comment: Could you write one or more literal examples, e.g. `string = "blabla y the_blabla_I_want (42) blabla"`. Are the parentheses around the number supposed to be there in the literal string? Are e.g. 3-digit numbers disallowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To represent `(two_digits_number)`, you may use `"\([0-9]{2}\)"`.

Here is a [regex tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) in python.

To get `the_blabla_I_want`, you may try the following code:

```
import re
x = re.search("y (.*) \([0-9]{2}\)", str)
x[1]
```

Depends on how you define the two digits number, yo may want to change `"\([0-9]{2}"` to `"\([1-9][0-9])"` to avoid numbers have leading zero

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "blabla y the_blabla_I_want (99) blabla"
if string.count("(") == 1 and string.count(")") == 1: 
    start_idx = string.find("(")
    end_idx = string.find(")")
    two_digits_number = string[start_idx+1:end_idx]
    print(two_digits_number) # output: 99
    two_digits_number = string[start_idx:end_idx+1]
    print(two_digits_number) # output: (99)
```